# Effective theory for ω → π + γ → 3γ radiative meson decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mesons

Looking for accounts of omega-mesons decaying, eventually, into three photons, I found (just) the old

M. Feldman et. al.: "Neutral Decay of the ω Meson", Phys. Rev. 159, 1219 (1967) ([doi:10.1103/PhysRev.159.1219](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.159.1219))

where a corresponding measurement is reported and found to be consistent with the assumption that all such decays go via

$\omega \to \pi^0 + \gamma \to (\gamma + \gamma) + \gamma$

If anyone could point me to further and more recent discussion of this decay, I'd be grateful. Does anyone discuss an effective field theory with a direct $\omega \to 3 \gamma$ vertex?

Comment: I am not experienced in this sort of thing, but effective lagrangians for vector mesons are not as routine as for pseudoscalars...